# How to create an extra line in csv file for indesign

Tags: csv, adobe-indesign

I'm creating an CSV file in excel which will be used in an Indesign document.

Is there a way to create an extra line (*like you do with alt+enter in excel*) in your csv file?

I tried /n, /r, "text", even double ""text""
all of these didn't create an new line in Indesign for me.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue many moons ago and got around it via the following:

1. Enter a unique symbol in the CSV where you want the line break to appear
2. Data Merge
3. Then Edit - Find/Change
4. Enter the unique symbol in the find field
5. Enter end of paragraph symbol (^p) in replace field

Comment: Nope, still not the trick for me. The symbol is trapped inside the generated text of the CSV and Indesign cannot find it to change the symbol.

Comment: how do you mean 'trapped inside the generated text'? Did it merge in successfully?

Comment: The text inside indesign, cannot be changed when it is merged via csv. The symbol is there, you can search it, but you cannot change it.